# Share OpenGraph Action Types Across Applications

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm currently trying to figure out whether it is possible for Applications to share a custom OpenGraph Action.

I.e. Application A specifies Action B, is a user with a token from Application C allowed to post an action B, but appears with all the relevant meta information of Application A?

Specifically, I'm Application C on which the users are logged in. Users will perform an action on Website A, which Website A wants me to publish on Facebook via Action B. However, we want Application A of Website A to define Action B, since it is supposed to drive traffic to Website A and not to me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question months later: No that is not possible